# Why does GridBagLayout think my component won't fit the container?

Tags: java, swing, gridbaglayout

GridBagLayout appears to be behaving strangely, but under some very specific conditions - could someone run the attached code under the following conditions and explain the resizing behaviour of the page preview panel towards the bottom of the window:

1. Run the code - don't input a name at the top - press and hold down the up button for the cells across spinner until the page preview changes to one page - the preview should not have (and will not have been resized)
2. Run the code again - enter "Hello World" (or any TWO words starting UPPERCASE) in the name field - press and hold down the up button for the cells across spinner until the page preview changes to one page - the preview is resized as if it won't fit the window and interferes with the button.

Why does the layout manager seem to think the PagePreview can no longer fit? Its dimensions haven't been touched by the setBreaks() method. And why would the nature of the string entered in the text field affect this?

This behaviour is even more noticeable if the getWidth() and getHeight() methods aren't overridden in the PagePreview class.

Sorry this isn't a shorter SSCCE but I couldn't replicate this problem without the full code.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSpinner;
import javax.swing.SpinnerModel;
import javax.swing.SpinnerNumberModel;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

import javax.swing.JSpinner.DefaultEditor;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.border.BevelBorder;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ResizeProblem extends JDialog implements ActionListener {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    new ResizeProblem(100, 75);

}

private int designWidth;
private int designHeight;

private JLabel nameLbl;
private JTextField nameField;
private JLabel printDesignLbl;
private JCheckBox printDesign;

private static final double PAGE_RATIO = 0.68;
private static final int PORTRAIT_ACROSS = 40;
private static final int LANDSCAPE_ACROSS = 60;
private int acrossValue;
private int downValue;
private boolean isPortrait;
private JLabel portraitLbl;
private JCheckBox portrait;
private JLabel landscapeLbl;
private JCheckBox landscape;

private JLabel acrossLbl;
private JSpinner across;
private JLabel downLbl;
private JTextField down;
private JLabel info;
private PagePreview preview;
private JButton print;

public ResizeProblem(int designWidth,
        int designHeight) {
    this.designWidth = designWidth;
    this.designHeight = designHeight;
    if (designWidth > designHeight) {
        isPortrait = false;
        acrossValue = LANDSCAPE_ACROSS;
        downValue = PORTRAIT_ACROSS;
    } else {
        isPortrait = true;
        acrossValue = PORTRAIT_ACROSS;
        downValue = LANDSCAPE_ACROSS;
    }
    setTitle("Print Options");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    setModal(true);
    setModalityType(ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
    setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    Format format = new Format();
    nameLbl = new JLabel("Project name (optional):");
    add(nameLbl, format.gbc_lw1);
    nameField = new JTextField();
    add(nameField, format.gbc_cw2);
    format.nextLine();

    printDesignLbl = new JLabel("Print design image:");
    add(printDesignLbl, format.gbc_lw2);
    printDesign = new JCheckBox();
    printDesign.setSelected(true);
    add(printDesign, format.gbc_rw1);
    format.nextLine();

    portraitLbl = new JLabel("Print design in portrait:");
    add(portraitLbl, format.gbc_lw2);
    portrait = new JCheckBox();
    portrait.setSelected(isPortrait);
    portrait.setActionCommand("portrait");
    portrait.addActionListener(this);
    add(portrait, format.gbc_rw1);
    format.nextLine();

    landscapeLbl = new JLabel("Print design in landscape:");
    add(landscapeLbl, format.gbc_lw2);
    landscape = new JCheckBox();
    landscape.setSelected(!isPortrait);
    landscape.setActionCommand("landscape");
    landscape.addActionListener(this);
    add(landscape, format.gbc_rw1);
    format.nextLine();

    acrossLbl = new JLabel("Number of cells printed across per page:");
    add(acrossLbl, format.gbc_lw2);
    SpinnerModel model = new SpinnerNumberModel(acrossValue, 20, 150, 1);
    across = new JSpinner(model);
    acrossValue = (int) across.getValue();
    downValue = getDownValue();
    across.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent arg0) {
            acrossValue = (int) across.getValue();
            downValue = getDownValue();
            down.setText(downValue + "");
            info.setText(getInfo());
            if (acrossValue <= designWidth || downValue <= designHeight) {
                preview.setBreaks(acrossValue, downValue);
            }
            repaint();
        }
    });
    ((DefaultEditor) across.getEditor()).getTextField().setEditable(false);
    ((DefaultEditor) across.getEditor()).getTextField().setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.LEADING);
    ((DefaultEditor) across.getEditor()).getTextField().setHighlighter(null);
    add(across, format.gbc_rw1);
    format.nextLine();
    downLbl = new JLabel("Corresponding printed down:");
    add(downLbl, format.gbc_lw2);
    down = new JTextField();
    down.setText(getDownValue() + "");
    down.setEditable(false);
    down.setCursor(null);
    down.setHighlighter(null);
    add(down, format.gbc_rw1);
    format.nextLine();

    info = new JLabel(getInfo());
    add(info, format.gbc_fulll);
    format.nextLine();

    preview = new PagePreview(designWidth, designHeight);
    preview.setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED));
    preview.setBreaks(acrossValue, downValue);
    add(preview, format.gbc_fullc);
    format.nextLine();

    print = new JButton("Print");
    print.setActionCommand("print");
    print.addActionListener(this);
    add(print, format.gbc_fullc);
    format.nextLine();
    add(new JLabel(), format.gbc_fullc);
    pack();
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setResizable(false);
    setVisible(true);
}

private int getDownValue() {
    int acrossValue = (int) across.getValue();
    if (isPortrait) {
        return (int) Math.ceil(acrossValue / PAGE_RATIO);
    } else {
        return ((int) (acrossValue * PAGE_RATIO));
    }
}

private String getInfo() {
    int pages = (getPagesAcross() * getPagesDown());
    if (pages > 1) {
        return "Design will be printed over " + pages + " pages";
    } else {
        return "Design will be printed on 1 page";
    }
}

private int getPagesAcross() {
    double pages = ((double) designWidth) / acrossValue;
    return (int) Math.ceil(pages);
}

private int getPagesDown() {
    double pages = ((double) designHeight) / downValue;
    return (int) Math.ceil(pages);
}

private void print() {
    dispose();
}

private void swapValues() {
    int temp = acrossValue;
    acrossValue = downValue;
    downValue = temp;
    across.setValue(acrossValue);
    down.setText(downValue + "");
    preview.setBreaks(acrossValue, downValue);
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    if (event.getActionCommand().equals("portrait")) {
        landscape.setSelected(false);
        isPortrait = true;
        swapValues();
    } else if (event.getActionCommand().equals("landscape")) {
        portrait.setSelected(false);
        isPortrait = false;
        swapValues();
    } else if (event.getActionCommand().equals("print")) {
        print();
    }
}

class Format {

    GridBagConstraints gbc_lw1;
    GridBagConstraints gbc_lw2;
    GridBagConstraints gbc_cw2;
    GridBagConstraints gbc_rw1;
    GridBagConstraints gbc_fulll;
    GridBagConstraints gbc_fullc;

    Format() {
        Insets insets = new Insets(20, 20, 0, 20);
        gbc_lw1 = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_lw1.gridx = 0;
        gbc_lw1.gridy = 0;
        gbc_lw1.gridwidth = 1;
        gbc_lw1.weightx = 0;
        gbc_lw1.weighty = 0;
        gbc_lw1.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
        gbc_lw1.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
        gbc_lw1.insets = insets;
        gbc_lw2 = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_lw2.gridx = 0;
        gbc_lw2.gridy = 0;
        gbc_lw2.gridwidth = 2;
        gbc_lw2.weightx = 0;
        gbc_lw2.weighty = 0;
        gbc_lw2.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
        gbc_lw2.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
        gbc_lw2.insets = insets;
        gbc_cw2 = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_cw2.gridx = 1;
        gbc_cw2.gridy = 0;
        gbc_cw2.gridwidth = 2;
        gbc_cw2.weightx = 1;
        gbc_cw2.weighty = 0;
        gbc_cw2.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;
        gbc_cw2.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc_cw2.insets = insets;
        gbc_rw1 = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_rw1.gridx = 2;
        gbc_rw1.gridy = 0;
        gbc_rw1.gridwidth = 1;
        gbc_rw1.weightx = 1;
        gbc_rw1.weighty = 0;
        gbc_rw1.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;
        gbc_rw1.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc_rw1.insets = insets;
        gbc_fulll = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_fulll.gridx = 0;
        gbc_fulll.gridy = 0;
        gbc_fulll.gridwidth = 3;
        gbc_fulll.weightx = 1;
        gbc_fulll.weighty = 0;
        gbc_fulll.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
        gbc_fulll.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
        gbc_fulll.insets = insets;
        gbc_fullc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_fullc.gridx = 0;
        gbc_fullc.gridy = 0;
        gbc_fullc.gridwidth = 3;
        gbc_fullc.weightx = 1;
        gbc_fullc.weighty = 1;
        gbc_fullc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        gbc_fullc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
        gbc_fullc.insets = insets;
    }

    void nextLine() {
        gbc_lw1.gridy++;
        gbc_lw2.gridy++;
        gbc_cw2.gridy++;
        gbc_rw1.gridy++;
        gbc_fulll.gridy++;
        gbc_fullc.gridy++;
    }

}

class PagePreview extends JPanel {

    private static final int BORDER = 10;

    private int width;
    private int height;
    private int designWidth;
    private int designHeight;
    private int xbreak;
    private int ybreak;

    public PagePreview(int designWidth, int designHeight) {
        this.designWidth = designWidth;
        this.designHeight = designHeight;
        width = designWidth + (BORDER * 2);
        height = designHeight + (BORDER * 2);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getWidth() {
        return width;
    }

    @Override
    public int getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public void setBreaks(int xbreak, int ybreak) {
        this.xbreak = xbreak;
        this.ybreak = ybreak;
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        g2d.drawRect(BORDER - 1, BORDER - 1, designWidth, designHeight);
        g2d.fillRect(BORDER - 1, BORDER - 1, designWidth, designHeight);
        if (xbreak > 0 && ybreak > 0) {
            g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            int breakpoint = xbreak;
            while (breakpoint < designWidth) {
                g2d.drawLine(BORDER + breakpoint, 0, BORDER + breakpoint, height);
                breakpoint += xbreak;
            }
            breakpoint = ybreak;
            while (breakpoint < designHeight) {
                g2d.drawLine(0, BORDER + breakpoint, width, BORDER + breakpoint);
                breakpoint += ybreak;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: I'd start by not overriding `getWidth/height`

Comment: @MadProgrammer I am overriding getWidth/Height in the page preview class,  this stops the component from being physically resized but the layout manager seems to think it will no longer fit and so doesn't make room for it. I am also at a loss as to why a pretty specific format of string inputted into the text field would have any impact at all on the layout on the y axis.

Comment: I did some playing around, overrode getPreferredSize instead of getWidth/height and adjusted the constraints to use `gridWidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER` and added `weightx = 1` which seemed to fix the issues, as to why, I don’t know (for sure)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thanks for your time and effort - I tried at least half a dozen permutations of what you suggested and none of them worked for me. I have managed to solve it by adding setMinimumSize() to the PagePreview class and removing all other overridden methods. It confuses me a bit as to why this works though because I've always been under the impression that GridBagLayout basically ignores minimum size. I use GBL quite a lot so maybe I should set aside a day (or three) to really dig into the code to fully understand how it works. Anyway, thanks again.